# Why does my Slate query work in edit mode but not consumer mode?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-slate

When I view my Slate document in edit mode, everything looks fine, but in consumer mode, no data is showing up in the widgets. I determined that the queries work in edit mode but not in consumer mode - what would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by a broken partial.

Although there is no straightforward way to debug partials, you can try pasting them into a query, and using the render button to see if there are any issues rendering the partial contents.

Also be sure to check that all your partials are the right type (SQL, Foundry, HTTPJSON) for the queries that reference them.